# How to force Docker to recreate container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

in docker-compose it is possible to run
`docker compose up container --force-recreate`.

Is there a way to do that with docker (i.e. without docker-compose)?
Would `docker container_name restart` have the same effect?

Comment: `docker stop` the container, `docker rm` it, and `docker run` a new one.  `restart` is a different verb (and `stop`/`rm`/`run` will give you more consistent results).

Comment: please reply as an answer so that I can mark it as a correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `docker stop` the existing container, then `docker rm` it, then `docker run` a new container with the same options as the original one.

`docker restart` is the equivalent of `docker stop` followed by `docker start`.  This restarts the main container process, but in the same temporary container filesystem.  If the container startup does things like generate configuration files or initialize data directories, the "old" data from the previous main process will be left behind; processes that maintain a pid or lock file to prevent concurrent execution might still see the old one.  Deleting a container and running a new one is usually preferable to starting a stopped one.

You do have to remember the complete set of `docker run` options yourself.  For Compose they're written down in the Compose file.  If there are more than a couple of options – something more complex than `docker run --name x -p 12345:54321 image-name` – consider creating a shell script to (re)start the container with a known set of options.